# Is siri open API available currently?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, siri

There is an app in app store name Touchpad, its last updated at Nov 29, included a new feature that supporting "Use the Siri key on device keyboard to send text to computer", I wanna to know if any open API for Siri right now, especially for iOS 5.1 beta, or how can it support such feature? Sorry that I have not the 4S and never try Siri.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Apple provide an API for SIRI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857353/does-apple-provide-an-api-for-siri)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is NO api for siri, but if siri is supported in your language then a microphone will be shown in the keyboard allowing you to dictate an text.

Comment: Then I was just confusing by its description for the update "Now support Siri"...

Comment: I would say they just made there app buzzword compatible.

Comment: Just wait until iOS 5.1 isn't under NDA, and it will all make sense.

Answer (score 3):

No, Siri is using a very closed protocol and/or API.

That is has been hacked is very unfortunate (but also awesome and a damn good job of reversing)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If no any open API, then how does the app I mentioned work? Maybe as the answer from @rckoenes (Thanks), it just shift the input language to enable text typing by Siri, that's all...But why such app especially mention in the update "Now support Siri", what did it change to adopt the new api?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of sources which suggest that a very limited portion of the Siri API (specifically dictation) will be exposed to developers in the upcoming iOS 5.1

http://www.freakgeeks.com/2011/19239/siri-for-third-party-applications/

http://www.sn0wbreeze.ca/ios-5-1-beta-add-siri-apis-and-battery-issues-are-still-there/

http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2011/11/ios-51-beta-offers-developers-limited-siri-integration.ars

Comment: A yes that is correct only the NDA does not allow us to talk about it.

Comment: Commenting on information in the public domain doesn't actually break the NDA as long as you don't reveal additional confidential information, though it is usually much smarter for those of us with access to the betas not to say anything to avoid confirming or denying these sort of rumours (which would add extra information), or accidentally mentioning new information.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unofficial, but @applidium have cracked the Siri protocol, so you can call Siri via HTTP.

Basically, you'll need to get a device GUID (see link below), send the raw audio (as speex audio codec) and you get back zipped data. Unzip the binary response (after 4th byte), and it contains plists.

URL: https://guzzoni.apple.com/ace
Http method: ACE

See more details: http://www.ps3trophies.com/forums/apple/6458-siri-cracked-now-even-android-users-can-use-siri.html