# Can I use Siri in my program?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, siri

There is a way to use the iPhone' Siri technology in my program?

Ex: When the user say "do this", than I config my program to do some action.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Apple provide an API for SIRI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857353/does-apple-provide-an-api-for-siri)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at this time, there is no access to Siri for developers yet.

Comment: @Rodrigo I don't think you can do it even with private framework at this time. It looks like a small portion of the API (dictate) will be available for iOS 5.1

Answer (score 1):

You can use Siri to send SMS or email to a remote server pre-configured for that device, and then have that server send push notifications to the app.