# Where is iOS 6 Siri API

Tags: ios, siri

I read numerous press releases claiming that Apple would make Siri's API available in iOS, but now that Siri has been released I cannot find any documentation for the said API on developer.apple.com

Comment: That's not true. There's no real Siri API available in iOS 6.

Comment: So the rumours were not true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Apple provide an API for SIRI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857353/does-apple-provide-an-api-for-siri)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rumors were incorrect, there is no Siri API (yet, hopefully).

Answer (score 3):

There are third party APIs, never used it before, so I can say if it is good or not.

Nuance:

http://news.cnet.com/8301-1035_3-57487441-94/nuance-unveils-nina-a-siri-sister-that-lives-in-third-party-apps/