# Siri in your application

Tags: ios, macos, siri, sirikit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Apple provide an API for SIRI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857353/does-apple-provide-an-api-for-siri)

Is there a way to add Siri to your OSX and iOS  applications ?

and If so,  how do you get Siri to process your own words as a command

If you say "Client"  Then because this is a register word/sound/key
it then performs action A  or calls function A ?

Can this be done anyone know ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is not related to Xcode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is a duplicate, I'll give you an answer. No. Apple supplies no API's for Siri, yet. We are expecting them in the future, so prepare for it. However, at the moment, they have absolutely no choices for you.

Also, since OS X doesn't have Siri itself, obviously it does not have a Siri API either. Cheers! :)