# SiriKit support for general services

Tags: ios, sirikit

I have watched SiriKit in wwdc and read document.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/

> Add SiriKit support only if your app implements one of the following
>   types of services:
>
> - Audio or video calling
> - Messaging Payments
> - Searching photos
> - Workouts
> - Ride booking

I am still wondering whether I can do for other services (since my app will be for enterprise app).

My service will be very simple searching only like "Find SQ212 in myapp".

Can it be done? I afraid that sirkit can't support intent for other servies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Apple provide an API for SIRI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857353/does-apple-provide-an-api-for-siri)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. That's why it says "***only if*** your app implements one of the following types of services".

You won't get the 'find `foo` in `bar`' syntax; each respective service has its own syntax - like "start a workout in MyApp" or "Book a ride to `place` with MyApp". See https://developer.apple.com/sirikit/ for examples.

I would expect a workaround using the SiriKit API to result in your app being rejected if submitted to the general app store, and I would expect it to be *extremely* fragile if it passed App Review or didn't go through it in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this article](https://swifting.io/blog/2016/07/18/20-sirikit-can-you-outsmart-provided-intents/) on making Sirikit Extensions that aren't default ones provided by Apple on swifting.io.

**Using INVocabulary**

From the Apple documentation:

> The INVocabulary object lets you augment your app’s fixed vocabulary with terms that are both unique to your app and to the current user of your app. Registering custom terms provides Siri with the hints it needs to apply those terms appropriately to the corresponding intent objects. You may register only specific types of custom terms, such as the name of a contact, the name of a user’s workout, a custom tag applied to a photo, or a user-specific payment type.

```
public enum INVocabularyStringType : Int {
    case contactName
    case contactGroupName
    case photoTag
    case photoAlbumName
    case workoutActivityName
    case carProfileName
}
```

**INMessage**

Here they use INSearchForMessagesIntent to setup an index search for finding support.

```
struct SupportMe{
static let systems = [
INPerson(personHandle: INPersonHandle(value: "MyNotes",
 type: INPersonHandleType.unknown),
 nameComponents: nil,
 displayName: "MyNotes",
 image: nil,
 contactIdentifier: "MyNotes",
 customIdentifier: "MyNotes")]

static let articles = [
INMessage(identifier: "MyNotesPassword",
  content: "Retrieving password in MyNotes app. To retrieve
   password use 'forgot password' button that is located below
   sign in button. Then type email address that your account has
   been assigned to and press reset password",
  dateSent: Date(),
  sender: SupportMe.systems[0],
  recipients: [SupportMe.systems[0]])]
}

extension IntentHandler: INSearchForMessagesIntentHandling{
func handle(searchForMessages intent: INSearchForMessagesIntent,
 completion: (INSearchForMessagesIntentResponse) -> Void){
    let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: String(INSearchForMessagesIntent.self))
    let response = INSearchForMessagesIntentResponse(code: .success,
     userActivity: userActivity)
    response.messages = [SupportMe.articles[0]]
    completion(response)
}
}
```

Comment: This isn't allowed by Apple, but if the developer isn't concerned with that, this should work.